# Too big error of numerical integrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to do some numerical integrate with Mathematica, but the results are very different from others' result calculated by C code. Here is my code:

```
\[HBar] = 1.05458*10^-34
eV = 1.6*10^-19
(*Subscript[k, B]=1.380649\[Times]10^-23*)
\[Epsilon]Au[\[Omega]_?NumericQ] := 
 1 - 8.9^2/(((\[HBar]*\[Omega])/eV) ((\[HBar]*\[Omega])/eV + 0.035 I))
\[Epsilon]electron[\[Omega]_?NumericQ] := 
 12.9 + (0.263645*1.0)^2/(((\[HBar]*\[Omega])/
       eV) ((\[HBar]*\[Omega])/eV + 0.0105438*I))
n[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] := 
 1/(E^(\[HBar]*\[Omega]/(1.380649*10^-23*T)) - 1)
kair[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := \[Sqrt]((\[Omega]/(3.0*10^8))^2 - k^2)
kau[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := \
\[Sqrt](\[Epsilon]Au[\[Omega]]*(\[Omega]/(3.0*10^8))^2 - k^2)
kelectron[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := \
\[Sqrt](\[Epsilon]electron[\[Omega]]*(\[Omega]/(3.0*10^8))^2 - k^2)
kgaas[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := \[Sqrt](12.9*(\[Omega]/(3.0*10^8))^2 - k^2)
RGaAsAirTE[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := (kair[\[Omega], k] - 
    kgaas[\[Omega], k])/(kair[\[Omega], k] + kgaas[\[Omega], k])
RGaAsAirTM[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := (12.9*kair[\[Omega], k] - 
    kgaas[\[Omega], k])/(kgaas[\[Omega], k] + 12.9*kair[\[Omega], k])
RAuAirTE[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := (kair[\[Omega], k] - 
    kau[\[Omega], k])/(kair[\[Omega], k] + kau[\[Omega], k])
RAuAirTM[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := (\[Epsilon]Au[\[Omega]]*kair[\[Omega], k] - 
    kau[\[Omega], k])/(kau[\[Omega], k] + \[Epsilon]Au[\[Omega]]*
     kair[\[Omega], k])
RGaAselectronTE[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := (kgaas[\[Omega], k] - 
    kelectron[\[Omega], k])/(kgaas[\[Omega], k] + 
    kelectron[\[Omega], k])
RGaAselectronTM[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := (\[Epsilon]electron[\[Omega]]*kgaas[\[Omega], k] - 
    12.9*kelectron[\[Omega], k])/(\[Epsilon]electron[\[Omega]]*
     kgaas[\[Omega], k] + 12.9*kelectron[\[Omega], k])
R2TE[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := (RGaAsAirTE[\[Omega], k] + 
    E^(2 I*kgaas[\[Omega], k]*1.3*10^-9)*
     RGaAselectronTE[\[Omega], k])/(1.0 + 
    E^(2 I*kgaas[\[Omega], k]*13*10^-9)*RGaAsAirTE[\[Omega], k]*
     RGaAselectronTE[\[Omega], k])
R2TM[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, 
  k_?NumericQ] := (RGaAsAirTM[\[Omega], k] + 
    E^(2 I*kgaas[\[Omega], k]*1.3*10^-9)*
     RGaAselectronTM[\[Omega], k])/(1.0 + 
    E^(2 I*kgaas[\[Omega], k]*13*10^-9)*RGaAsAirTM[\[Omega], k]*
     RGaAselectronTM[\[Omega], k])
d = 10; \[Omega] = 10^10; (\[HBar]/(4*\[Pi]^2))*
  NIntegrate[(n[\[Omega], 3000] - n[\[Omega], 300])*
    k*((Im[Log[
           1 - E^(2 I*(d)*10^-9*kair[\[Omega], k])*R2TE[\[Omega], k]*
             RAuAirTE[\[Omega], k]]]*
         (UnitStep[
            k - \[Omega]/(3.0*10^8)]*(Im[
              R2TE[\[Omega], k]*Conjugate[RAuAirTE[\[Omega], k]]]/
             Im[RAuAirTE[\[Omega], k]*R2TE[\[Omega], k]])) + 
        Im[Log[1 - 
            E^(2 I*(d)*10^-9*kair[\[Omega], k])*R2TM[\[Omega], k]*
             RAuAirTM[\[Omega], k]]]*
         (UnitStep[
            k - \[Omega]/(3.0*10^8)]*(Im[
              R2TM[\[Omega], k]*Conjugate[RAuAirTM[\[Omega], k]]]/
             Im[RAuAirTM[\[Omega], k]*R2TM[\[Omega], k]]))) + (Im[
          
          Log[1 - E^(2 I*(d)*10^-9*kair[\[Omega], k])*
             R2TE[\[Omega], k]*RAuAirTE[\[Omega], k]]]*
         (UnitStep[\[Omega]/(3.0*10^8) - 
             k]*((Abs[RAuAirTE[\[Omega], k]]^2 - 
               Abs[R2TE[\[Omega], k]]^2)/(1 - 
               Abs[R2TE[\[Omega], k]*RAuAirTE[\[Omega], k]]^2))) + 
        Im[Log[1 - 
            E^(2 I*(d)*10^-9*kair[\[Omega], k])*R2TM[\[Omega], k]*
             RAuAirTM[\[Omega], k]]]*
         (UnitStep[\[Omega]/(3.0*10^8) - 
             k]*((Abs[RAuAirTM[\[Omega], k]]^2 - 
               Abs[R2TM[\[Omega], k]]^2)/(1 - 
               Abs[R2TM[\[Omega], k]*
                 RAuAirTM[\[Omega], k]]^2))))), {k, 0, 10^10}, 
   MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 200, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 1000, 
     Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

My result is 7.86024E-19, and the others' result is 3.75816E-18, about 5 times bigger than my result. And when I set [Omega] to 10 or 10^16, there will be an error

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 1000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 8.64013728426451`*^16 and 1.1122311774396058`*^14 for the integral and error estimates.
```

Besides, the integrate is a little slow(about 13s), is there any more efficient way to do such calculation?

Comment: `εelectron` is defined with a single argument; however, in the definition of `RGaAselectronTM` it is used with two arguments. An undefined function precludes numeric evaluation.

Comment: Do you have any advice to improve it? Should I change them to a single function?

Comment: The code that you posted does not evaluate. Since you obtained a result, what you evaluated is not what you posted. You need to determine what the difference is. At a minimum, either the definition of `εelectron` or `RGaAselectronTM` is wrong. the definition of `RGaAselectronTM` is suspect since it includes `εelectron` with two arguments and one of the two arguments there is `p` which is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, it is a mistake that I forgot to delete `p` when I change the code. I have corrected it now. Besides, the NIntegrate needs 30s when the method is GolobalAdaptive, 7s when the method is LocalAdaptive. The results are the same. Is there any other way to speed up?

Comment: The use of `?NumericQ` with a function's arguments is unnecessary if the function doesn't use a numeric technique that would fail with a nonnumeric value. If you remove all of the unnecessary `?NumericQ` tests, then your code will be faster.

Comment: If you apply `//Simplify` after definition of every intemediate function you use, you do not need any options to NIntegrate and integration is done in less than one second. Further, are you sure, your calculation in `C ` is right? You use constants with largely differing accuracies.